# Access ftp from Azure

Tags: azure, ftp

I tried to connect to my ftp sever from Azure Server using window cmd (dos).
The connection succeeds, but then, all other commands like ls, dir, put, get,...failed

It generates the following message without completing the task (never finished):

```
150 opening data channel for file upload to server (for commande put),

or 150 opening date channel for directory list (for commande ls)
```

Although I added a new outbound to allow port 21 in windows Firewall with the following characteristic (profile: all, enabled:yes, action: allow, override:no, program: any, local address: any, remote address: any, Protocol: TCP, local port: any, remote port:21, Authorized computers: any, Authorized  local principals: any, Local user owner: any, application package: any).

Am I missing something?

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is? why can't I use any of the commands?

From my local pc it works. I success to get, put files, list directory, etc..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an FTP server with a passive configuration (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464003(v=ws.10).aspx). When using this mode, the 21 port is using to establish the connection but other operations are done trough a collection of ephemeral ports.

Review your configuration because maybe you need to add the ephemeral port range also to your Firewall: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd463996(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks jangelfdez. I think also that it is a firewall problem